# Localize default msi string using wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

How can i localize the the string to different languages(Korean,Japanese) that displays during msi installation, ex:preparing to Install(image below), using wix. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Most likely your Korean/Japanese customers work with UI Culture of the OS set to Korean/Japanese. In this case, the dialog you referenced is displayed in the target language by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This exactly message is coming from windows installer service itself, it's the same for all installations, and you can't change it, it's always in the OS language.